# Having problems with Gem Red-Arrow installing to Ruby on Rails project

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

When I try to `gem install red-arrow -v 3.0.0` in docker image based on LinuxKit with `'rails', '~> 6.0.3'`, I get the following error:

```
# gem install red-arrow -v 3.0.0
Building native extensions. This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing red-arrow:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    current directory: /usr/local/bundle/gems/red-arrow-3.0.0/ext/arrow
/usr/local/bin/ruby -I /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.6.0 -r ./siteconf20211103-1947-7io2n7.rb extconf.rb
checking --enable-debug-build option... no
checking C++ compiler... g++
checking g++ version... 8.3 (gnu++14)
checking for --enable-debug-build option... no
checking for -Wall option to compiler... yes
checking for -Waggregate-return option to compiler... yes
checking for -Wcast-align option to compiler... yes
checking for -Wextra option to compiler... yes
checking for -Wformat=2 option to compiler... yes
checking for -Winit-self option to compiler... yes
checking for -Wlarger-than-65500 option to compiler... yes
checking for -Wmissing-declarations option to compiler... yes
checking for -Wmissing-format-attribute option to compiler... yes
checking for -Wmissing-include-dirs option to compiler... yes
checking for -Wmissing-noreturn option to compiler... yes
checking for -Wmissing-prototypes option to compiler... yes
checking for -Wnested-externs option to compiler... no
checking for -Wold-style-definition option to compiler... yes
checking for -Wpacked option to compiler... yes
checking for -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 option to compiler... yes
checking for -Wpointer-arith option to compiler... yes
checking for -Wundef option to compiler... yes
checking for -Wout-of-line-declaration option to compiler... no
checking for -Wunsafe-loop-optimizations option to compiler... yes
checking for -Wwrite-strings option to compiler... yes
checking for Homebrew... no
checking for arrow version (>= 3.0.0)... yes
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
    --with-opt-dir
    --without-opt-dir
    --with-opt-include
    --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
    --with-opt-lib
    --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
    --with-make-prog
    --without-make-prog
    --srcdir=.
    --curdir
    --ruby=/usr/local/bin/$(RUBY_BASE_NAME)
    --enable-debug-build
    --disable-debug-build
    --enable-debug-build
    --disable-debug-build
    --with-pkg-config
    --without-pkg-config
    --with-override-variables
    --without-override-variables
/usr/local/bundle/gems/pkg-config-1.4.6/lib/pkg-config.rb:389:in `parse_pc': .pc doesn't exist: <thrift> (PackageConfig::NotFoundError)
    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/pkg-config-1.4.6/lib/pkg-config.rb:233:in `declaration'
    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/pkg-config-1.4.6/lib/pkg-config.rb:178:in `requires_private'
    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/pkg-config-1.4.6/lib/pkg-config.rb:509:in `block in all_required_packages'
    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/pkg-config-1.4.6/lib/pkg-config.rb:259:in `collect_requires'
    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/pkg-config-1.4.6/lib/pkg-config.rb:265:in `block in collect_requires'
    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/pkg-config-1.4.6/lib/pkg-config.rb:260:in `each'
    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/pkg-config-1.4.6/lib/pkg-config.rb:260:in `collect_requires'
    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/pkg-config-1.4.6/lib/pkg-config.rb:508:in `all_required_packages'
    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/pkg-config-1.4.6/lib/pkg-config.rb:283:in `collect_cflags'
    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/pkg-config-1.4.6/lib/pkg-config.rb:191:in `cflags_only_other'
    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/pkg-config-1.4.6/lib/pkg-config.rb:569:in `cflags_only_other'
    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/pkg-config-1.4.6/lib/pkg-config.rb:616:in `have_package'
    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/glib2-3.4.9/lib/mkmf-gnome.rb:458:in `required_pkg_config_package'
    from extconf.rb:28:in `<main>'

To see why this extension failed to compile, please check the mkmf.log which can be found here:

  /usr/local/bundle/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.6.0/red-arrow-3.0.0/mkmf.log

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in /usr/local/bundle/gems/red-arrow-3.0.0 for inspection.
Results logged to /usr/local/bundle/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.6.0/red-arrow-3.0.0/gem_make.out
#
```

My docker file:

```
FROM ruby:2.6.6

ENV RAILS_ENV=production
ENV NODE_VERSION 10.24.1
ENV SPA_ORIGIN our.url.com
ENV SECRET_KEY_BASE 1

RUN mkdir -p /app

RUN apt-get update -qq \
 && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
 && apt-get -y autoremove \
 && rm -rf /var/cache/apt

RUN \
  curl -SLO "https://nodejs.org/dist/v$NODE_VERSION/node-v$NODE_VERSION-linux-x64.tar.xz" \
  && sha256sum node-v$NODE_VERSION-linux-x64.tar.xz \
  && echo "somekey  node-v$NODE_VERSION-linux-x64.tar.xz" | sha256sum -c - \
  && tar -xJf "node-v$NODE_VERSION-linux-x64.tar.xz" -C /usr/local --strip-components=1 \
  && ln -s /usr/local/bin/node /usr/local/bin/nodejs \
  && rm node-v$NODE_VERSION-linux-x64.tar.xz

WORKDIR /app
COPY config/puma.rb config/puma.rb

COPY Gemfile Gemfile
COPY Gemfile.lock Gemfile.lock

RUN apt-get update -qq \
  && apt install -y -V ca-certificates lsb-release \
  && wget https://packages.red-data-tools.org/$(lsb_release --id --short \
  | tr 'A-Z' 'a-z')/red-data-tools-apt-source-latest-$(lsb_release --codename --short).deb \
  && apt install -y -V ./red-data-tools-apt-source-latest-$(lsb_release --codename --short).deb

RUN apt-get update -qq \
  && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends ca-certificates lsb-release \
  && curl -o /tmp/apache-arrow.deb -SL https://apache.jfrog.io/artifactory/arrow/$(lsb_release --id --short | tr 'A-Z' 'a-z')/apache-arrow-apt-source-latest-$(lsb_release --codename --short).deb \
  && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends /tmp/apache-arrow.deb \
  && rm /tmp/apache-arrow.deb

RUN npm install -g yarn

RUN apt-get update -qq \
 && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends build-essential libparquet-glib300\
 && bundle install --without development test \
 && apt-get purge -y build-essential \
 && apt-get -y autoremove \
 && rm -rf /var/cache/apt

RUN yarn install

COPY . .

RUN bin/rake assets:precompile

RUN rails webpacker:compile

EXPOSE 3000

CMD ["bundle", "exec", "puma", "-C", "config/puma.rb"]
```

Comment: Hi Alexey, is it possible if you could share how your Dockerfile looks like?

Comment: Hi Farhad!
Dockerfile was added.

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to setup apache thrift.

https://thrift-tutorial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html

add this snippet to your dockerfile.

```
RUN \
  apt-get install -y ant libboost-dev libboost-test-dev libboost-program-options-dev libboost-filesystem-dev libboost-thread-dev libevent-dev automake libtool flex bison pkg-config g++ libssl-dev && \
  wget --no-check-certificate http://dlcdn.apache.org/thrift/0.15.0/thrift-0.15.0.tar.gz && \
  tar -xvf thrift-0.15.0.tar.gz

WORKDIR ./thrift-0.15.0
RUN \
  ./bootstrap.sh && \
  ./configure && \
  make && make install
```

Answer (score 0):

The 6.0.0 release of Apache Arrow (currently the latest release) did not list out the libthrift-dev dependency which [caused  this missing pkg-config error](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/ARROW-14724).

It has since been [fixed](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/ARROW-14486) and is set to be released sometime soon in Apache Arrow 6.0.1

In the meantime, you can install `libthrift-dev` (no need to build from source) before you install arrow:

```
apt-get install -y -V libthrift-dev
```